# Google query to get Special domain tld

Tags: google-search

What query should i search to get one special domain tld with google ?

For example,

I want to get all domain names in google results with this TLD : `.info` .

What query should i search in google ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you're looking for `site:info`.

If you add that to your query, you'll limit the results to only sites under `info`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
site:.info
```

Check out the search modifiers documentation for more

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to search like this :

```
inurl:www.*.info
```

But of cource the domain name should have `www` in the first of the indexed page,

The other choice is this :

```
site:.info
```